# Case Merge: What happens with related records

Tags: custom-object, case, merge

We have custom objects that are related to the Case object. Until now we have been using custom case merge functionality, but it has its bugs, and are exploring moving over to the new SF case merge functionality. Does anyone know what happens to related records on Case when cases are merged?

Comment: can't speak for cases but when you merge Accounts or Contacts, all related objects become children of the merge winner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_merge.htm&type=5) clearly states:

> When you merge cases, you select one case to be the master ... All
> related lists, feed items, and child records are added to the master.